# Is a power set's base set uniquely determined?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is a power set's base set uniquely determined? More precisely, if $\mathcal{P}(S) = \mathcal{P}(T)$, does that imply $S=T$?

Comment: can you think of a counterexample?

Comment: @user107952 There is actually an even more general relation taking place: for any two sets $M$ and $N$, the inclusion $\mathscr{P}(M) \subseteq \mathscr{P}(N)$ entails the inclusion $M \subseteq N$. Try to see if you can find the reason for this being so, it is not difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure; we can prove the contrapositive. Suppose that $S \neq T$, so that there is (say) $a \in T \backslash S$. Then $\{a\} \in \mathcal{P}(T)$ but $\{a\}\notin \mathcal{P}(S)$, so $\mathcal{P}(S) \neq \mathcal{P}(T)$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\bigcup\mathcal{P}(A) =A$, the base is unique.